# PHP variables to array

Tags: php

I often see or have to convert a bunch of variables into an array like this:

```
$array = array("description"=>$description, "title"=>$title, "page"=>$page, "author"=>$author);
```

Basically, all array keys match the name of the variable that is being passed in. Is there a way to reference a variable name so that it can be passed into the array like so:

```
$array[varName($description)] = $description;
```

Comment: Seems like this is the wrong approach. If the values have already been saved to variables, that seems to imply you had the opportunity to store them as array keys in the first place??

Comment: @mavili How can `variable variable` be helpful here?

Comment: it doesn't, does it? I shall remove that then ;)

Comment: not a dupe, as indicated by the answer by Felix King.

Answer (score 11):

You could use [`compact` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php):

```
$array = compact('description', 'title', 'page', 'author');
```

Each argument is a variable name and it will create an array with the key being the name and the value being the value of the variable with that name.

It's the other way round than your approach though.

Comment: +1 Never heard of `compact` before

Comment: +1 @MathieuImbert Me neither - but can't help thinking it seems a bit "hackish"?

Comment: Never heard of compact, +1!

Comment: @Emissary, if you think this is hackish, I'd avoid most of PHP! :) (not disagreeing with your assessment however).

Comment: @StackOverflowed Disagree! you can't blame the language for how people are using it :) `compact` to me seems like one of them legacy functions that you should never need if you stick to conventional coding practices?

Comment: @Emissary Perhaps, but then you're talking about a language that JUST added "goto" statements. Seriously. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Comment: @StackOverflowed I can't fault you there - if I ever catch one of my subordinates using that I'll be telling them where they can goto...